# Creating one line of output for my result using a CURSOR

Tags: sql, plsql

I'm successful to acquire the data I need but I wish to put the results as a continuous string separated by pipes here is my sample code

```
    CONNECT mgs/mgs;
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

DECLARE
  CURSOR PRODUCT_SUMMARY_CURSOR IS
    SELECT PRODUCT_NAME ,LIST_PRICE FROM PRODUCTS
     ORDER BY LIST_PRICE DESC;
  PRODUCT_SUMMARY_ROW PRODUCTS%ROWTYPE;  
BEGIN
  FOR PRODUCT_SUMMARY_ROW IN PRODUCT_SUMMARY_CURSOR LOOP
   IF (PRODUCT_SUMMARY_ROW.LIST_PRICE > 700) THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('"' || PRODUCT_SUMMARY_ROW.PRODUCT_NAME || '",' || '"' || PRODUCT_SUMMARY_ROW.LIST_PRICE || '"' || '|');
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how many products you are going to be processing the below should work.  If the string gets to long then you might need to look at using a clob rather than a varchar2.

```
CONNECT mgs/mgs;
    SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

DECLARE

  v_output_string varchar2(4000) default null;

  CURSOR PRODUCT_SUMMARY_CURSOR IS
    SELECT PRODUCT_NAME ,LIST_PRICE FROM PRODUCTS
     ORDER BY LIST_PRICE DESC;
  PRODUCT_SUMMARY_ROW PRODUCTS%ROWTYPE;  
BEGIN
  FOR PRODUCT_SUMMARY_ROW IN PRODUCT_SUMMARY_CURSOR LOOP
   IF (PRODUCT_SUMMARY_ROW.LIST_PRICE > 700) THEN
     v_output_string := v_output_string || '"' || PRODUCT_SUMMARY_ROW.PRODUCT_NAME || '",' || '"' || PRODUCT_SUMMARY_ROW.LIST_PRICE || '"' || '|';
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
  dbms_output.put_line(v_output_string);
END;
/
```